# How to build a docker image within jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a jenkins maven job and trying to build a docker image. When I build the image with this command:

```
docker build ./docker/ -t containers.test.com/78/tools
```

I get this error:

> docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'

I have rechecked and checked this command dozens of times. I've even tried running it directly in the terminal. It works in the terminal but not in jenkins. Is there something I am missing?

I am using Docker version 1.12.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it is

```
docker build -t foo/bar .
```

^ the dot (.) at the end of the line designates current path to use as Docker context.
Try a `cd` to docker folder?

Comment: I tried a cd to docker then tried this command `docker build . -t containers.test.com/78/tools`. It still didn't work.

Comment: At the very end must be a space and a dot, or target folder

Comment: ok I tried this. `docker build -t containers.test.com/78/tools .`. Still no luck. Notice I put a space between path and dot. I got this error: `dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?" `

Comment: Is docker running? - Docker ps.

Comment: in the latest command what is missing is the `sudo` prefix for the docker command. However, if this is an automated build in Jenkins, you won't be able to use `sudo`, so you need to add user jenkins to the docker group so that it can fire docker commands: `usermod -aG docker jenkins`.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. Didn't have jenkins configured right

Comment: side note: is now DevOps SE not more suitable place for this question?